# Screen goes white when setting home display to static on server site (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, templates, cyberduck

:)

I have made a Wordpress site, which I have migrated from local to a server. I have created a one pager with images in the bottom that links to the different post of my site. I have used the plugin Advanced custom fields in order to make my site editable.

After a lot of searching online, I found that it was not possible to add custom fields to your index php directly but that you could make a template in which you copied all your old code from the index.php into.

I got it to work on my local host by going to Settings - Readings in my wordpress admin panel an under set my homepage displays as static - Homepage (which is the name of my template).

But when I try to do the same thing on the server site, the screen goes white... Maybe it is something with the file structure?

I've taken a screen shot of whole the files are located in my FTP (Cyberduck). I don't know if its enough to help..

Thanks in advance[image]

```
<div class="section" id="section2"> 
<div class="row">  
<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6" id="left">
    <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/imgs/pen.png" id="pen" class="img-fluid animation"  alt="Responsive-image"/>
    <lol><h2 id="About">3 Facts</h2></lol>
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6" id="right">
     <div class="image_field d-none d-md-block">  <!-- image field-->
            <?php $post_image = get_field('avatar_image')['sizes']['large']; ?>
            <img src = "<?php echo $post_image; ?> " id="avatarimage" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">  
        </div>


    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/imgs/Onefinal.svg" id="One"/> <!-- class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive-image" -->
            <div class="container" id=text>
        <?php
                $my_query = new WP_Query('pagename=hej');
                while ($my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
                the_content();
                endwhile;
                wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your setup in "Settings - Readings"?

Answer (score 0):

Template of the static homepage should be stored in a file called `front-page.php` which needs to be placed in `/wp-content/themes/elnino` directory.

Copy code of your template (except comment with template name) and paste it inside `front-page.php` file.

```html
<div class="section" id="section2">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6" id="left">
            <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/imgs/pen.png" id="pen" class="img-fluid animation" alt="Responsive-image" />
            <lol>
                <h2 id="About">3 Facts</h2>
            </lol>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6" id="right">
            <div class="image_field d-none d-md-block">
                <!-- image field-->
                <?php $post_image = get_field('avatar_image')['sizes']['large']; ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $post_image; ?> " id="avatarimage" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/imgs/Onefinal.svg" id="One" />
                <!-- class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive-image" -->
                <div class="container" id=text>
                    <?php
                        $my_query = new WP_Query('pagename=hej');
                        while ($my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
                        the_content();
                        endwhile;
                        wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: So just to be sure - everything except <?php /*Template Name: Home  */ ?>

Comment: Exactly, that's what I meant.

Comment: When I did that the last time, the whole site crashed.. I am new in Wordpress so I am a little afraid of going into the wp-config.php file :/

Comment: You can duplicate current wp-config file, so you will have a backup ;)

Comment: I enabled debug and it gave me the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /net/fshome1.itu.dk/export/home1/mtws/public_html/elnino/wp-content/themes/elnino/front-page.php on line 38, where it says: <?php $post_image = get_field('avatar_image')['sizes']['large']; ?>

Comment: Can you show me the code of front-page.php? Somewhere between line 30 and 50

Comment: yes I am adding it in my main question - there are too many characters to add it as a comment

Comment: Sorry mistake, now it is added

Comment: Anyway, functions cannot be ended with '[', ']' brackets. Delete '['sizes']['large']' from line 38.

Comment: Now it is up, but now my custom field images are not showing. :/ It just shows this little icon of an image ( like it does not want to load). Should I ask the question in another thread maybe?